# Open Google Maps place on iOS with Universal Link

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm using Universal Links to open a place in Google Maps since I don't really see another way.

I create a normal Google Maps links like this, which on web resolves to a place:

```swift
let urlString = String(format: "https://www.google.com/maps/place/?q=place_id:%@", annot.cafe.google_place_id)
```

Then I tap it on iOS and get Google Maps opened with the error that no such place could be found.

Should this work? Is there some other way to focus a specific place on iOS Google Maps?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is possible using a search URL construction as specified here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#search-action

The constructed URL needs to have both the `query` with the lat/lon coordinates in it and a `query_place_id` with the place id.

It looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=52.504875%2C13.394549&query_place_id=ChIJoaO7QRRRqEcRtBLLz6p4PS0
```

That creates the desired behaviour of the map going to the location and displaying details for the given place.